# How to change the path of a mapped drive in win7?

Tags: windows-7, mapping

[image]

Now it's mapped to `\\192.168.248.128`,how to change it to `\\192.168.66.2` instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create another mapped network drive:

- right-click the current drive and click "Disconnect"
- right-click "Computer" and select Map Network Drive
- configure the new drive

If you want Windows API you can use [WNetAddConnection2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385413%28VS.85%29.aspx).

If you want a BAT (command line) you can try [net use](http://www.computerhope.com/nethlp.htm) command line option.

Answer (score 60):

If you want to use the **command line** have a look to the **next answer** below!

But you can also edit the settings in Windows Registry: '`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Network\[Drive letter]`'

When you now open a new '*My Computer*' window  - after changing the target in registry -  you will likely see the old settings, but that is only a visual problem. Try to open the entry, and it should work!

Have a look to Chris Budys interesting comment below, that fixes obviously the visual problem.

Comment: +1. This IS an answer to the question "How to **change** ...".

Comment: This answer put me on the right path, and if you do a find in the registry for the path you are changing you will find a few more locations that can be updated:

* HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Map Network Drive MRU

* HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MountPoints2\##0.0.0.0##ShareName

After updating all of those everything works as expected and displays properly as well.

Answer (score 32):

`net use` can modify a drive in place without deleting and recreating. You simply execute the command as if you're mapping a new drive, and it replaces it instead. The command syntax is:

```
net use [Drive name] [UNC path]
```

Example:

```
C:\> net use U: \\192.168.66.2
U: has a remembered connection to \\192.168.248.128. Do you
want to overwrite the remembered connection? (Y/N) [Y]: y
The command completed successfully.
```

Comment: This should really be turned into the accepted and/or most upvoted answer. It's correct, does exactly what the OP asks, doesn't requiring searching registry key(s) or multiple steps and as such is also pretty much the fastest way to get there.